# MS ACCESS 2007 - Table/Query Structure for a Metrics Database

Tags: database, ms-access, relational-database

Apologies in advance if this is hard to follow, but my question is more conceptual than technical, for those of you out there who have some experience designing this kind of thing.

I'm trying to decide the best way to structure my feeder tables and queries to connect metrics with their measures and objectives.

My metrics database has two primary feeder tables:

- tblDissem (with Organization/Project/SubProject columns being
  relevant)
- tblVolume (With Organization/Project/SubProject/Analyzed/Shared
  columns being relevant)

There are approximately 50 measures organized into 10 objectives in tblMeasures, with foreign keys for OrganizationID, ProjectID, SubProjectID for each measure.  The 10 objectives in themselves aren't distinct enough where I can simply create a query for each (it'd have to be a union query after the fact).

The metrics for each measure are based on one of the following:

- Count of tblDissem, organized by
  Organization/Project/SubProject/Fiscal Quarter
- Sum of tblVolume.Analyzed, organized by
  Organization/Project/SubProject/Fiscal Quarter
- Sum of tblVolume.Shared, organized by
  Organization/Project/SubProject/Fiscal Quarter

As it is now, I have select queries set up for each of the two feeder tables converting dates to fiscal quarters, and crosstab queries for each of the above broken out by quarter for each organization/project/subproject.

The challenge is in getting these organized by objective.  I figured I could create a query for each group of measures, then use union queries to  organize each into their proper objective, OR I add a field to tblMeasures that lists the measure as either a DissemCount, AnalyzedSum, or SharedSum measure, which I'd somehow build into another query to automatically group the query results.  Or, maybe use a lookup field in a way I haven't considered yet.

I'm open to any ideas, and apologies for being so abstract.  Thanks in advance...I'm just not an expert when it comes to the *how* of relating information.

Comment: I think adding a measure type field to tblMeasures would be a good start.  What do you mean by "the objectives in themselves aren't distinct enough"?  It's hard to tell more without seeing some sample data.

Comment: I'll try and throw some sample data here, or a diagram.  If the objectives were grouped better (i.e. one measure "type" for each), then I could just have a query linking each group of measures to their metrics.  The query links them by organization/project/subproject but I'm not sure it's the cleanest or most efficient way to do it.